# Print transaction multiple times in same A4 sheet on daily basis

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have multiple products, at end of the day, I need to update the stock book which contains all the product and other parameters associated to the product as a hard copy. Right now staff is updating the entry manually in the book.

Now the products increased and it is difficult to update the stock book manually.

- There is an POS mobile app to generate invoice, we can also view the product stock in app itself.
- In-order to comply with government rules and regulations it is mandatory to maintain hard copy of the stock book of all product with the department specified format and same needs to updated in daily basis.
- I will export the stock details from the mobile POS as excel, with that need to generate the required format.

**I am looking for any open source tool or logic to print transaction in the same A4 sheet repeatedly.** .

- Example 15 entries in 1 side and next 15 entries in other side of A4 sheet.
- So i have 50 products i needs to print 50 A4 sheets.

Staff will be maintaining the sheet order while feeding it to the printer.

My thoughts is to generate the PDF with table containing the transaction details of that particular day.

- Example, i want to print transaction for Day 4 of the month, then 4th row in the table alone contains the  details.
- So i need to generate PDF with 50 pages for 50 products.
- No borders for the table.
- If it is the 1st row in the page, PDF will contain Header and 1st row with transaction details.